# How to implement ajax based search in Django powered website

Tags: python, ajax, django

I want to implement search functionality used by this [website](http://www.couponland.in/) on my Django powered website.
 Can someone suggest me a way to implement this in Django based website.Are their any app like endless-scrolling for Django to implement ajax based feature in your site ??.Or best way is to write every thing from scratch ......

Answer (score 0):

Try a mix of [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) + RESTFul django backend. Another option is [AngularJS](http://www.angularjs.org/)

This two framework can be used to build a very good Ajax frontend with little dependency on the backend (which is always a good thing by the way).
For a complete example [see this code](http://www.verious.com/code/mjumbewu/django-backbonejs/) and also [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430940/calling-a-python-function-within-a-backbone-js-view)

Answer (score 0):

The big cadillac solution:
[Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/%20%22Backbone%22%20+) + [Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) + [Django rest_framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/)

The small economy car solution:
You could also get allot of bang really quick by using one of these jQuery plugins.

[DataTables](https://datatables.net/) or [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)

finally [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/intro.html) could be used to give you the grid layout if you so desire.